# How to insert a numpy array to a numpy array of arrays?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a simple question here, I have three arrays,

```
a = np.array([1,2,3])
b = np.array([4,5,6])
c = np.array([7,8,9])
d = np.array([6,6,6])
```

I combine a,b,c to another array say e,

```
e = np.array([a,b,c])
```

I want d to be inserted to e so that I get the following output,

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [6,6,6]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`numpy.append`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.append.html#numpy.append) that appends to the end of array:

```
e = np.append(e, [d], axis=0)
```

Note as quoted from docs:

> Append values to the end of an array. When axis is
>   specified, values must have the correct shape.